# не могу завершить цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = []
m = 0
print ("добавьте элемент в список.")
a.append(input())
while m<1:
    u1 = str(input("Добавить ещё один элемент?y/n"))
    if u1 == "Y" or "y":
        print ("добавьте элемент в список.")
        a.append(input())
    else:
        m+=2
print(a, "- ваш список")
print("Вы можете:")
print("Удалить элемент из списка. Введи 'remove'")
print("Очистить список. Введи 'clear'")
print("Добавить ещё один элемент (на место i).Введи 'insert'")
print("Сложить все элементы.Введи 'sum' ")
u2 = str(input("Ваша операция: "))
if u2 == "remove":
    a.remove(input("Значение которое собираетесь удалить из списка"))
    print(a)
elif u2 == "clear":
    a.clear()
    print(a)
elif u2 == "insert":
    i = intinput(("На какое место хотите вставить элемент ?"))
    x = float(input("что вставить?"))
    a.insert(i,x)
    print(a)   
elif u2 == "sum":
    nm = sum(a)
    print(a)
else:
    print("Вашей операции не существует.")
```

Не понимаю из-за чего я не могу завершить 1 цикл ?

Comment: `if u1 == "Y" or "y"` всегда истинно. вероятно имеется в виду `if u1 == "Y" or u1 == "y"`

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно потому, что эта конструкция `if u1 == "Y" or "y":` работает не так, как вам кажется. Она проверяет, что переменная `u1` равна "Y" или строка "y" истинна. Так как непустая строка всегда истинна, ветка `else` никогда не будет выполняться. Судя по всему, вам нужно такое условие `if u1 == "Y" or u1 == "y":` или такое `if u1 in ("Y", "y"):`.

Comment: Верно ! Именно это и встретилось

Comment: @ArtSem если ответ помог вам, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).