# Помогите подправить прогу на пайтоне

Tags: python

```py
print("Как вас зовут?:")
name=input()
print("Привет"+","+name+"!")

a=["Программирование","Убраться в комнате","Погулять"]

spisok=input("Вам сегодня нужен список задач?:")
if spisok=="Да" or "Нужен" or "нужен" or "да":
    print(a)
if spisok=="Нет" or "нет":
    print("Но всё же посмотрите его позже")

 else:
 print("я не понимаю")
```

Comment: Вероятный дубликат вопроса: [не могу завершить цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/970341/204271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Как вас зовут?:")
name=input()
print("Привет"+","+name+"!")

a=["Программирование","Убраться в комнате","Погулять"]

spisok=input("Вам сегодня нужен список задач?:")
if spisok=="Да" or "Нужен" or "нужен" or "да":
    print(a)
if spisok=="Нет" or "нет":
    print("Но всё же посмотрите его позже")

else:
     print("я не понимаю")`введите сюда код`
```

Попробуй так, если я правильно понял

Comment: Дружище,код тот же,без изменений.Ты ошибся,кажется

Comment: @RickSanchez, нет, здесь добавлен отступ. Отступы в питоне важны.

Answer (score 0):

Также можно улучшить

```
spisok=input("Вам сегодня нужен список задач?:").lower()
if spisok=="нужен" or "да":
    print(a)
```